# Uploaded file at sftp its empty

Tags: php

With this code I create a zip file and I uploaded to a SFTP server, all is correct except that the uploaded zip on the server doesnt work; its size is only 14 bytes and I can't open it if I download it.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip_name = './temp/'.time() . ".zip";
if ($zip->open($zip_name, ZipArchive::CREATE) === TRUE) {
    foreach ($dir_content as $file) {
        if ($file != '.' && $file != '..' && !is_dir($dir_route . '/' . $file)) {
            $zip->addFile($dir_route . '/' . $file);
        }
    }
    $zip->close();
}

if (file_put_contents('ssh2.sftp://' . SFTP_USER . ':' . SFTP_PASSWORD . '@' . SFTP_HOST . ':' . SFTP_PORT . '/dades/' . $zip_name, $zip_name)) {
    echo "Fichero subido con éxito";
} else {
    echo 'Ocurrió un problema al enviar los ficheros';
}
```

Comment: Are you sure the file on the local machine is correct before uploading it?

Comment: Yes, the local file it's correct

Comment: Is it reporting that the upload is successful? I can't think of a reason why it would upload only part of the file, but not report an error.